# React Ace Selection Change Event Not Getting Trigger

Tags: reactjs, ace-editor, react-ace

Ace Control Code:

```
<AceEditor
                  mode="mysql"
                  theme="tomorrow"
                  name="UNIQUE_ID_OF_DIV"
                  value={queries ?? ""}
                  editorProps={{ $blockScrolling: true }}
                  onChange={(e) => {
                    setqueries(e);
                  }}
                  onSelectionChange={handleSelectionChange}
                />
```

Methods:

```
const handleSelectionChange = (selectedText, event) => {
    setSelectedQueries(selectedText);
    console.log("selectedText", selectedText);
  }
```

Here in `selectedText` i am getting `selection` object which does not hold any `selectedText`.

How can i get SelectedText on React-Ace editor?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved,

```
 const aceEditor = useRef();

<AceEditor
                  ref={aceEditor}
                  mode="mysql"
                  theme="tomorrow"
                  name="UNIQUE_ID_OF_DIV"
                  value={queries ?? ""}
                  editorProps={{ $blockScrolling: true }}
                  onChange={(e) => {
                    setqueries(e);
                  }}
                  onSelectionChange={(v, e) => {
                    setSelectedQueries(aceEditor.current.editor.getSelectedText())
                  }}
                />
```

Make sure you are adding `ref={aceEditor}` in your `AceEditor` control.